# Something wrong in configuration accordion jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, configuration

Well i'm ussing .accordion() in my website buy i'm try to configurate with the next code:

```
$("#acordeon").accordion({
                       collapsible: true,
                       autoHeight: false,
                       heightStyle: "content",
                       active:false
                   });
```

But isn't works... when i'm navigate in the accordion, the height is too bigger in some cases and i don't know why.... I'm looking for the mistakes but in others blogs the solution is the same like my code :( :(

Example to my HTML... the content it's always the same

```
        <div id='acordeon'>
        <h3>Example1</h3>
        <div class='content'>
        <ul>
        <li>other contents</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too, or together in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry, i'm forgot to put any example....

Comment: You need to be more specific.. I tried your code in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9hhLjy3/) and I see nothing wrong. Review your HTML code (id's, classes for elements) with how you apply CSS properties to it. Any suspicious overriding? Also, make sure you properly load jQuery core + jQuery UI.

Comment: Yes i'm load jQuery+jQuery ui ... i'm founded the problem: the jQuery ui styles! I needed made some changes and now works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's the jQuery ui styles... I needed changed the property height there and now works! Thanks for the help!